# How to change the mouse cursur of OneNote 2010?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I saw in Onenote 2010 that the pointer is not a dot but a pencil/pen. I tried to check how to change the shape of it but i couldn't.

[image: Image of mouse cursor shaped like a pen]

How can I change the cursor?